Firebase realtime database always return null list while using viewmodel
Firebase realtime database always return null list while using viewmodel/livedata. But if I use the same code in Fragment itself it works.
this is my viewmodel
package com.example.taxinfo.viewmodel

import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.example.taxinfo.adapters.HomeAdapter
import com.example.taxinfo.modelClass.TaxDetails
import com.example.taxinfo.repository.UserRepo
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener

class UserViewModel(val repo : UserRepo) : ViewModel() {

    private lateinit var reference: DatabaseReference

    private val _taxDetails = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<TaxDetails>>()
    val taxDetails : LiveData<ArrayList<TaxDetails>> get() = _taxDetails
    fun getTaxDetails(context: Context){

        val list = arrayListOf<TaxDetails>(TaxDetails("1000", "HouseLoan"))
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Tax Details")

        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    for(snap in snapshot.children){
                        val taxData = snap.getValue(TaxDetails::class.java)
                        if (taxData != null) list.add(taxData)
                    }
                    _taxDetails.value = list
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(context, error.toException().localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }

    fun saveTaxDetails(id : String, amount : String, itemSelected : String, context : Context, view : View){
        repo.saveTaxDetails(id, amount, itemSelected, context, view )
    }
}


This is my fragment
package com.example.taxinfo.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.taxinfo.R
import com.example.taxinfo.adapters.HomeAdapter
import com.example.taxinfo.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding
import com.example.taxinfo.modelClass.TaxDetails
import com.example.taxinfo.viewmodel.UserViewModel
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding : FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

    private lateinit var reference: DatabaseReference

    private lateinit var list : ArrayList<TaxDetails>

    private val viewModel : UserViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.plusButton.setOnClickListener {
            Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_accountFragment)
        }

        // recyclerview


        viewModel.getTaxDetails(requireContext())
        viewModel.taxDetails.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            if (it != null) list = it
        })

        recyclerView.adapter = HomeAdapter(requireContext(), list)

        recyclerView = binding.recyclerView

        recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)


        list() //calling list adapter

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun list() {
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tax Details")
        val list = arrayListOf<TaxDetails>()

        reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    for(snap in snapshot.children){
                        val taxData = snap.getValue(TaxDetails::class.java)
                        list.add(taxData!!)
                    }
                    try {
                        recyclerView.adapter = HomeAdapter(requireContext(), list)
                    }catch (e : NullPointerException){
                        Log.d("TAG", e.localizedMessage)
                    }

                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), error.toException().localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })

    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        _binding = null
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
}

If I try to get the list from database using the function in the fragment, it works but if I use Viewmodel observer to get the list, it returns null and app crashes

According to the Kotlin code sample in this documentation you need to call setValue to ensure LiveData picks up the change.

Have you tried Frank's recommendation?

Clearly a NPE .. You are passing null list to HomeAdapter .. Create the adpater after list is initialized or initialize the list as empty instead of lateInt ..

I initialized the list as empty and it worked. Thanks SpiritCrusher
